# How to Add Call-to-Action Button Inside Tweets via Twitter API

Tags: twitter

Will be very thankful if somebody could share their experience how to add call-to-action button inside tweets which posted through Twitter API:
[POST statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update)

**Expected result**

1. **Subscribe** button inside tweet

[image]

2. After clicking on this button Subscription dialog appears

[image]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.twitter.com/ads/reference/post/accounts/%3Aaccount_id/cards/website

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Test Website Card 1",
    "id": "g9z",
    "preview_url": "https://cards.twitter.com/cards/abc1/g9z",
    "created_at": "2014-05-18T21:29:18Z", 
    "card_type": "WEBSITE",
    "updated_at": "2014-05-18T21:29:18Z",
    "website_cta": "READ_MORE",
    "account_id": "abc1"
  },
   "data_type": "card",
   "request": {
    "params": {
     "name": "Test Website Card 1",
     "card_type": "WEBSITE",
     "account_id": "abc1",
     "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/peacock/398520248267071488/image.jpg",
     "website_url": "https://support.twitter.com/",
     "website_title": "Twitter Help Center",
     "website_cta": "SUBSCRIBE",

    }
  }
}
enter code here
```

The bottom line, "website_cta": "SUBSCRIBE", will set the call-to-action (cta) to subscribe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Seems like adding call-to-action buttons is a part of *Advertisement API* not regular status update. Have all that wanted to know. Thanks.